# Difference between "allow notifications" toggle and dragging to "do not include"

Tags: settings, notifications, ios

In iOS 8, the **Settings > Notification Center** has changed with the addition of an **Allow Notifications** toggle for each app.

If you toggle this to "off", the app will automatically go down into the **DO NOT INCLUDE** area.

However, if you leave the toggle "on", you can also manually drag the app down into the **DO NOT INCLUDE** area.

In the latter case, there is still text under the app indicating what types of notifications it has ("banners, sounds, badges" etc).

So what is the difference between these two situations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting an app Do Not Include will not include notifications from that app in the Notification Center. If you do not disable the other notifications then you will still receive the notifications on the lock screen and if you are using the device, but the notifications won't remain in Notification Center. Conversely, if you disable the notifications then the app is automatically moved to Do Not Include as the app will never appear in the Notification Center if there are no notifications.